# BizTalk 2013r2 (Visual Studio 2013) - Default Property Schema configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2013, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm developing in BizTalk 2013R2 using Visual Studio 2013, trying to create a property schema based on a large, lengthy source schema using Quick Promotion, however I'm having difficulty getting the created property schema generated properly.

Essentially we are trying to adhere to cleaner development standards that mean BizTalk solution artefacts are nested within their own relevant folders, but some of the automated functionality of the VS SDK for BizTalk is making this seemingly impossible.

Is it possible to create a Property Schema in a specific directory within your solution root?
I don't seem to be able to enter a full filepath into the 'Default Property Schema' option on the source schema properties, as it errors with an 'illegal characters' warning for spaces and backslashes in the filepaths string.
I've tried using HTML encoding, escape characters and encapsulating it as a string, but they just return the same error each time.

I've also tried generating the schema in the root source, and then moving it manually into my target folder, changing the namespace accordingly to reflect its new location, but this loses it's connection within the source property schema and causes the link to break.

Comment: Apologies - I've been on leave and just catching up :) Yes that gave me the answer I needed thanks, I've got quite a large prop schema and manually pointing each element is a slightly tedious task, but needs must!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible

After you have done your quick promotion, go into the Promote Properties and remove the Promoted Properties (1) and then the schema (2)

[image: Removing Promoted Properties screen1]

After that move and change the namespace of the Promoted Properties schema.

And then browse for the property schema (1) in the Promote Properties dialog and then select the item to promoted (2), click Add (3) and if you have more than one promoted property assign it to the correct one (4).

[image]